# Is there a hook in ember data i can use to know when it actually sends request to the server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to show spinner only if data is not in the store (if ember sends request to the server)

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current state of models.

Your Controller:

```
savingObserver: function(){
  this.set('showSpinner', this.get('model.isSaving'));
}.observes('model.isSaving')
```

If that is true, show spinner.

Or if you have multiple records to watch, do this:

```
savingObserver: function(){
  this.set('showSpinner', this.get('content').isAny('isSaving', true);
}.observes('content.@each.isSaving')
```

Comment: looks interesting, what is record? i have `this.store.find('item', {client:client}),` in my model. How do i know when it will be saving the results?

Comment: In this case, record is one "item" you get from store.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Hmm im getting Undefined is not a function for 'isAny'. I put savingObserver into my controller. Am i missing something? And +1 for the idea ;)

Comment: i dont think content is enumerable

Comment: It could be helpful to provide an example on jsbin. So I can see your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

`save` returns a promise, you can infer it's started right before you've called `save` and infer it's finished after the promise has resolved.

```
console.log('saving');
record.save().then(function(){
  console.log('done saving');
}); // finally might be more appropriate in case it fails
```

You can also hook up to `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` and put a spinner there [Showing a spinner during an AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509044/showing-a-spinner-during-an-ajax-request)

Comment: i have multiple records and i dont think that using ajaxStart in ember is `clean` if that makes sense..

Comment: It's perfectly fine, Ember itself isn't an ajax library, so any way you do it is outside of Ember.  Ember Data also isn't an ajax library, it's a record management library, which uses jquery for its ajax calls, but it does provide promises which give you the most `Ember Data` way of seeing when a model is saving.  And when you're working with multiple records that could be saved at once, using a push pop strategy with `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` is probably the cleanest solution.